# How to pass touch coordinates to fragment shader from java?

Tags: android, opengl-es, glsl

I am new to Opengl and I am currently using fragment Shader to change some pixel color of image by touch effect but I don't know how to pass touch coordinates to fragment shader from java.

Comment: I support you because question is interest. You need to provide some code source attempt if you wanna quick answer...

Comment: This is my updated question   @NikolaLukic                                                                 Please Help me to do this.          https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56087305/how-do-i-create-free-hand-mask-on-image-like-below-using-glsl-shader-in-android

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use uniform variables. These are variables, whose values are set in Java. However, they are accessible in the GLSL shader programs.

Example of a shader class:

```
private int programId;
private int vertexShaderId;
private int fragmentShaderId;

private int uniformLocation_touchCoordinates;

public MyShader(String vertexShader, String fragmentShader) {
    vertexShaderId = //load vertex shader;
    fragmentShaderId = //load fragment shader;

    programId = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(programId, vertexShaderId);
    glAttachShader(programId, fragmentShaderId);

    //bind in variables of the vertex shader here

    glLinkProgram(programId);
    glValidateProgram(programId);

    //init uniform variables
    uniformLocation_touchCoordinates = glGetUniformLocation(programId, "touchCoordinates");
}
public void bind() {
    glUseProgram(programId);
}
public void unbind() {
    glUseProgram(0);
}

public void loadTouchCoordinates(float x, float y) {
    glUniform2f(uniformLocation_touchCoordinates, x, y);
}
```

fragmentShader:

```
//version tag, input and output variables

uniform vec2 touchCoordinates;

void main(void) {
    //...
}
```

Usage:

```
public class Renderer {
    MyShader shader = new MyShader(..., ...); //pass shader code

    public void render() {
        shader.bind();

        //update uniform variable with your data
        shader.loadTouchCoordinates(..., ...); //pass coordinates

        //do your render logic here

        shader.unbind();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for Answering, I will try it definitely.